# How to disable div when we click on outside of div in blazor?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, blazor

I have two div on one page, one is right side and another one is left side,
I want to close or hide the left side div whenever we click on right side of div.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="rightDiv" @onclick="fn_ShowHide()"> </div>
<div id="lefttDiv"  hidden="@IsShow"  > </div>
```

@code {

```
private void fn_Hide()
{
     IsShow =   !IsShow;
}
```

}

Comment: You're not explaining what you're doing here, and it's also incorrect.
Blazor prefers the use of `@if {}` blocks for showing and hiding elements.